# Passing a 2D array of strings to a function in c++

Tags: c++, c, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to pass a 2d and single dimmension array of strings to a function but its not working.

my arrays are:

```
    string 2Darray[100][100];
    String 1Darray[100];
```

Now the function:

```
    void check(string temp2D[100][100], string temp1D[100]);
```

When I call it:

```
    check(2Darray,1Darray);
```

I've tried it other ways ad they all don't work.
Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: your 1Darray seems 2D to me

Comment: string 1Darray ,being a 1D array has two sets of indices , in its declaration ??

Comment: You cannot start identifiers with numbers in C++, i.e. `2Darray` needs to be `twoDarray`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change to accept references:

```
void check(string (&temp2D)[100][100], string (&temp1D)[100]);
```

or pointers:

```
void check(std::string temp2D[][100], std::string temp1D[]){}
```

which is the same as the following just different syntax:

```
void check(std::string (*temp2D)[100], std::string* temp1D){}
```

Also, you cannot start variable names with numbers, `2Darray`, etc. is a compiler error.

Here is a full working example:

```
#include <string>

void check(std::string (&temp2D)[100][100], std::string (&temp1D)[100]){}

int main()
{
    std::string twoDarray[100][100];
    std::string oneDarray[100];
    check(twoDarray,oneDarray);
}
```